# How to Run one Process Twice with shell script?

Tags: c++, linux, shell, shared-memory

If I have an executable, what is the correct way to run it twice with shell script ?
The process to be executed twice is using shared memory for message passing and shared semaphores
using simply

```
./a
./a
```

will run one process and other process can't run until first process stops and therefore no communication between two processes takes place
what is the right way to run one executable twice in parallel fashion ?

Comment: Put it in the background, using `&`.

Comment: ./a
nohup ./a &   
is it correct ?

Answer (score 1):

As [@SamVarshavchik said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40073537/how-to-run-one-process-twice-with-shell-script#comment67420325_40073537), use an ampersand to run a process in the background, so the other one can run concurrently:

```
./a &
./a
```

or

```
./a & ./a
```

Comment: ./a 
./a & 
Second process won't go in background due to execution of first 
is there any way to put the second process in background not the first (in case first process is interactive and second just needs to run in background) ...

Answer (score 1):

If, as your comments imply, the second process needs to be in the background because the first process is interactive, you can do:

```
{ sleep 10; ./second; } &
./first
```

---

Alternatively, you can start each process with its own Terminal:

```
xterm -e "./first" &
xterm -e "./second" &
```

Answer (score 1):

At first, instead of bash hacking, it would be better to rewrite your app and make it `fork()` on start. But in general, if you want to bring the first process to foreground you can use an `fg` command:

```
./a &
./a &
fg 1
```